# Trouble with a where clause which looks back 24 months from current date

Tags: hive, hiveql, impala

I have this where clause which works fine in Impala but is throwing an error in Hive. What I'm trying to do is only bring in data 24 months prior to the current day.

```
select * from my.database
where period_date > add_months(now(), -24);
```

Just erroring out and not producing any results.

Comment: *throwing an error* and *erroring out* are useless as a problem description without more information. Do you get an error message? If so, what is the exact message you're getting. If you don't get an error message, then what specifically does *throwing an error* mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike Impala, Hive does not have a `now()` function. It complies with ANSI SQL by providing `current_date` and `current_timestamp` registers (starting with version 1.2  [[ref]](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions)). So for Hive, this should work:

```
select * from my.database
where period_date > add_months(current_date, -24);
```